# HomePlugAV sees other HomePlugs but not the network

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I have a LAN which I have extended via HomePlugs.

`Cable Modem -> Ethernet -> HomePlug 1 -> Electrical Wiring -> HomePlug 2`

When HomePlug 2 is connected inside my house, everything works as expected.

When HomePlug 2 is connected in my garage, I experience problems.

- Devices attached can't see the network.
- No DHCP is issued by the modem.
- Etc.

Ordinarily, I'd put it down to crap wiring - but the HomePlug can see the other HomePlugs on the network!

Using the [HomePlug Device Manager](http://www.zibri.org/2009/03/powerline-ethernet-fun-and-secrets.html) I can see all HomePlugs on my network.  If I'm wired in to HomePlug2, and run the diagnostic tools, I can see the other units.

So, what would cause a HomePlug to be able to see the other plugs on the network, but not actually *be on* the network?

--

Added some screenshots showing the diagnostics when connected to the problematic plug.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Packet loss? ...

Comment: What colour lights on the units? Which speed are they? What kind of information does homeplug device manager give?

Comment: Power light on - Green. Network light on - Green. LAN port flashing - Green. Although I'm not sure if the units have mult-colour LEDs.  The Device Manager is showing the MAC addresses, no MPDU failures, source & destination as 100Mbps full duplex.

Comment: They do. IIRC I've seen orange and even red network lights in the past. While troubleshooting those things is a pain , design of those things are pretty consistant

Comment: From you screenshots and the blanked out mac addresses I cannot identify which screen shot belongs to which Adapter (bc:96:80:08:xx:xx vs. bc:96:80:08:xx:xx!?).

Comment: The last screen shot shows 0/0 and 9/11 Mbps. These are connections absolutely at the minimum where you cannot expect a useful connection. (This comment is only true if you tried to generate traffic, because only then the PHY rates are estimated and displayed.)